# Mysql can't get data of my parent in a subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've to do a query where the join can access to the data of is parent.
I had this :

```
SELECT  *
FROM tbl_quart q
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph ON ph.tbl_quart_id = q.id 
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc ON phc.tbl_poste_horaire_id = ph.id 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT q1.id,
        IF(q1.heureDebut>CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'24:00:00'),
               IF(q1.heureFin<CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'48:00:00'),q1.heureDebut)) AS heureTri
        FROM tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc1 
            INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph1 ON ph1.id = phc1.tbl_poste_horaire_id 
            INNER JOIN tbl_quart q1 ON q1.id = ph1.tbl_quart_id
        WHERE phc1.tbl_caserne_id = phc.tbl_caserne_id
        ORDER BY phc1.tbl_caserne_id, heureTri
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS quartValide ON quartValide.id = q.id
WHERE phc.tbl_caserne_id IN (1,9)
```

but this request give me that:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'phc.tbl_caserne_id' in 'where clause'
```

the error is for this line :

```
WHERE phc1.tbl_caserne_id = phc.tbl_caserne_id
```

I had also try this :

```
SELECT  *
FROM tbl_quart q
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph ON ph.tbl_quart_id = q.id 
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc ON phc.tbl_poste_horaire_id = ph.id 
WHERE phc.tbl_caserne_id IN (1,9) AND q.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT q1.id,
        IF(q1.heureDebut>CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'24:00:00'),
               IF(q1.heureFin<CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'48:00:00'),q1.heureDebut)) AS heureTri
        FROM tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc1 
            INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph1 ON ph1.id = phc1.tbl_poste_horaire_id 
            INNER JOIN tbl_quart q1 ON q1.id = ph1.tbl_quart_id
        WHERE phc1.tbl_caserne_id = phc.tbl_caserne_id
        ORDER BY phc1.tbl_caserne_id, heureTri
        LIMIT 2
        )
```

And i had an error too:

```
Error Code: 1235
This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: Do you really want `CURTIME()`?  It is now 13:09:11; adding 24 hours gives 37:09:11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT  *
FROM tbl_quart q
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph ON ph.tbl_quart_id = q.id 
    INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc ON phc.tbl_poste_horaire_id = ph.id 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT q1.id,
        phc1.tbl_caserne_id
        IF(q1.heureDebut>CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'24:00:00'),
               IF(q1.heureFin<CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q1.heureDebut,'48:00:00'),q1.heureDebut)) AS heureTri
        FROM tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc1 
            INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph1 ON ph1.id = phc1.tbl_poste_horaire_id 
            INNER JOIN tbl_quart q1 ON q1.id = ph1.tbl_quart_id
        ORDER BY phc1.tbl_caserne_id, heureTri
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS quartValide 
    ON quartValide.id = q.id AND quartValide.tbl_caserne_id = phc.tbl_caserne_id
WHERE phc.tbl_caserne_id IN (1,9)
```

but it would be better to refactor this query... give me a minute, I think we can simplify it.

it looks like you overcomplecated the query a little. Try this one and tell me what is wrong with result?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT q.*,
   ph.*,
   phc.*,
   IF(q.heureDebut>CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q.heureDebut,'24:00:00'),
   IF(q.heureFin<CURTIME(),ADDTIME(q.heureDebut,'48:00:00'),q.heureDebut)) AS heureTri
 FROM tbl_poste_horaire_caserne phc 
 INNER JOIN tbl_poste_horaire ph 
   ON ph.id = phc.tbl_poste_horaire_id 
 INNER JOIN tbl_quart q 
   ON q.id = ph.tbl_quart_id
 WHERE phc.tbl_caserne_id IN (1,9)
 ORDER BY phc.tbl_caserne_id, heureTri
 LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Having the LIMIT in the subquery is probably faster.